# How to set a password on 2nd SSD on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bios

I have Dell 3779 with 2 SSDs:

- Toshiba M.2 KBG30ZMS128G, used as primary drive (OS)
- Samsung EVO 860, used for data

In Bios settings I am able to set the password just for the OS drive.

Is there a way so secure the 2nd hard drive as well so it would be unlocked on boot time the same way as the primary one?

The goal is that in case of losing the laptop the 2nd drive with all data would not be easy accessible the same way as the primary is.

I am pretty sure this won't be possible via BIOS, so probably something with Windows 10?

The password for both drives can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt your 2nd hard drive with BitLocker and make it unlock by default when you log in to Windows.